# dlopen failed: could not load library "libfb.so" needed by "libreactnativejni.so"; caused by library "libfb.so" not found

Tags: android, facebook, android-ndk, react-native, android-library

I just want to use the react-native to my project, however , after i have added it. It got the error at the running time! Would someone help me? pls

```
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:301) 
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libfb.so" needed by "libreactnativejni.so"; caused by library "libfb.so" not found
   at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:350)
   at java.lang.System.load(System.java:512)
   at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary(DirectorySoSource.java:63)
   at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:209)
   at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:178)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutor.<clinit>(JSCJavaScriptExecutor.java:25)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutor$Factory.create(JSCJavaScriptExecutor.java:20)
   at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:183)
   at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:169)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:289)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: Hey how did you solve it

Answer (score 0):

it is a bug about using Jrebel for android plugin that i use in the android studio..